# Is there a way to install microdnf on amazoncorretto image?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile

I have a DockerFile with the following that works

```
FROM maven:3.8.4-openjdk-17
ARG CHROME_VERSION=113.0.5672.63-1
ADD google-chrome.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo
RUN microdnf install -y google-chrome-stable-$CHROME_VERSION \
    && sed -i 's/"$HERE\/chrome"/"$HERE\/chrome" --no-sandbox/g' /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome

ARG CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=113.0.5672.63
RUN microdnf install -y unzip \
    && curl -s -o /tmp/chromedriver.zip https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip \
    && unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip -d /opt \
    && rm /tmp/chromedriver.zip \
    && mv /opt/chromedriver /opt/chromedriver-$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION \
    && chmod 755 /opt/chromedriver-$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION \
    && ln -s /opt/chromedriver-$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION /usr/bin/chromedriver
```

This has (per https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/maven/3.8.4-openjdk-17/images/sha256-d07c45c45755f0f90b779bad869467e602f1bfff4d0b5eb1ff73f2882bc38187) amazonlinux:2, 2.0.20230612.0 as the base.

I wanted to try to use Amazon Corretto so I tried

```
FROM maven:3.9.3-amazoncorretto-17
ARG CHROME_VERSION=113.0.5672.63-1
ADD google-chrome.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo
RUN microdnf install -y google-chrome-stable-$CHROME_VERSION \
    && sed -i 's/"$HERE\/chrome"/"$HERE\/chrome" --no-sandbox/g' /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
```

Per https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/maven/3.9.3-amazoncorretto-17/images/sha256-51a8ceaec1ddb3237be298e8f31e794b0e047855d88d8ceae5dbb672606fe4a6 this has amazonlinux:2, 2.0.20230612.0 as a base image

However I get an error

```
[3/5] RUN microdnf install -y google-chrome-stable-113.0.5672.63-1  && sed -i 's/"$HERE\/chrome"/"$HERE\/chrome" --no-sandbox/g' /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome:
#7 2.618 /bin/sh: microdnf: command not found
```

So previously microdnf was coming from the base image but it is no longer doing so.

I then tried (per https://installati.one/centos/8/microdnf/):

```
=> ERROR [2/6] RUN yum -y install microdnf                                                                                                                                      29.3s
------                                                                                                                                                                                 
 > [2/6] RUN yum -y install microdnf:                                                                                                                                                  
#5 2.536 Loaded plugins: ovl, priorities                                                                                                                                               
#5 27.24 9 packages excluded due to repository priority protections                                                                                                                    
#5 27.85 No package microdnf available.
#5 28.56 Error: Nothing to do
```

Is there a way to figure out either how to install microdnf or is there a better way to install this?

Comment: I have no idea if this is the cause, but Amazon Linux 2 manages some packages as "extras"; see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/amazon-linux-ami-basics.html#extras-library

You might have to find out whether `microdnf` is one of the extras, and if yes enable it. Or it might be that the Maven Dockerfile installs that from somewhere else.